# Spring MVC Primefaces Ajax Fails when mapping request 404 error code

Tags: java, ajax, spring, primefaces

I'm trying to use p:commandButton from Primefaces within my server.

Page look ok untill I click on the button and nothing happens. I've checked console and it shows following error:

```
- POST http://localhost:8080/rest_test-0.0.1/WEB-INF/faces/order.xhtml 404 (Not Found)
send jquery.js.xhtml:21
bG.extend.ajax jquery.js.xhtml:21
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.send primefaces.js.xhtml:1
PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.offer primefaces.js.xhtml:1
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest primefaces.js.xhtml:1
PrimeFaces.ab primefaces.js.xhtml:1
onclick
```

My controller is mapped on

```
"http://localhost:8080/rest_test-0.0.1/orderService/"
```

so I can figure out it is not mapping properly.

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
         xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
         >
    <h:head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
                setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
            }
        </script>
    </h:head>
        <h:body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(45000);"> <!-- Reload every 45 secs -->
            <h:form id="ordersTableForm" >
                <p:dataTable var="order" value="#{orderContainer.orderList}">
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['order.label.nTable']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.tableNumber}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{msg['label.actions']}">
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg['order.label.finish']}" action="#{orderServiceController.finishOrderPost}">
                        <!--<p:commandButton value="#{msg['order.label.finish']}" action="finishOrderPost"> -->
                            <f:attribute name="tableNumber" value="#{order.tableNumber}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>    
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>

    Controller Method---

    @RequestMapping(value="finishOrderPost", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody void finishOrderPost(@RequestBody Integer tableNumber){
            log.info("##>> OrderServiceController finishOrder INI on table " + tableNumber + "<<");
            orderService.finishOrder(tableNumber);
        }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0">

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>order.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <!-- 
            SPRING ROOT WEB APPLICATION CONTEXT
        -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>        
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener> 

        <!-- 
            SPRING MVC
        -->

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <!-- <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-webflow.xml</param-value>
            </init-param> -->
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
         <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>  

        <filter>
            <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
            <servlet-name>Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
        </filter-mapping>

         <!-- 
            JSF 2 IMPLEMENTATION
        -->
        <!-- Use JSF view templates saved as *.xhtml, for use with Facelets -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
            <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- Enables special Facelets debug output during development -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- Causes Facelets to refresh templates during development -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
            <param-value>1</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize, *not* used at runtime -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <!-- PRIMEFACES -->

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

context config (spring-servlet.xml) and related

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pfc.restaurante" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <import resource="config/spring-datasource.xml"/>
    <import resource="config/spring-webflow.xml"/>
    <import resource="config/spring-webmvc.xml"/>


</beans>

/////////////7spring-webflow.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">

    <!-- 
        Enable processing of JSF 2 resource requests. For example:
        /context/app/javax.faces.resource/jsf.xhtml?ln=javax.faces
    -->
    <faces:resources />

    <!--
        Maps request paths to flows in the flowRegistry; e.g. a path of
        /registration-flow looks for a flow with id "registration-flow"
    -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <!--
        Dispatches requests mapped to flows to FlowHandler implementations
    -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Executes flows: the central entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location id="parent-flow" path="parent-flow.xml"/>
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
    <faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"  development="true"  />

    <!-- A listener to create and release a FacesContext -->
    <bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>


</beans>

spring-webmvc.xml

<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="jspInternalViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/faces/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

   <!--  <bean id="ajaxViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/faces/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean> -->
     <!--  JSF for representation layer. All JSF files under /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- <bean id="jspUrlViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/faces/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

       <!--  <property name="basename" value="src/main/resources/message/messages" /> -->
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="conversionService"
        class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="formatters">
            <set>
                <ref bean="dishTypeFormatter" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <!-- converts @ResponseBody String return types into the response body -->
            <bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>

            <!-- standard form encoding -->
            <bean id="formHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>   

            <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
            </bean>                                                             

        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <!-- Enables annotated methods on POJO @Controllers -->
    <!--  Replaced by "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/> -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
         <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jsonViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />

</beans>

///////////spring-hibernate.xml

<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- INI STORAGE -->

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/config/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>     
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm using maven:

```
Spring 3.1.2 RELEASE
Hibernate 4.1.7.Final
org.springframework.webflow 2.3.1.RELEASE
org.codehaus.jackson 1.9.12
com.fasterxml.jackson.core 2.1.4
javax.servlet 2.5
com.sun.faces 2.1.22
javax.servlet 1.2
primefaces 3.5
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can access "http://localhost:8080/rest_test-0.0.1/orderService/" to check is the controller is ready. can you give some information about the configuration such as web.xml , spring bean configuration files.

Comment: I added xml config content. I hope it helps. Thanks by hand.

Comment: Also I'm using org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver inside my faces-config.xml

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest_test-0.0.1/WEB-INF/faces/order.xhtml should be something like http://localhost:8080/rest_test-0.0.1/faces/order.xhtml