# Primefaces Ajax Fails with 404 error code

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, spring-web

I realized the ajax requests primefaces is making behind the scene, e.g. paging,wizard form, is failing. And when i check i console i see there's 404 error because the url used in making the request is not what is mapped by the controller.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXBV3.png)

```
jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0:25 POST http://localhost:8080/kenko-web/WEB-INF/views/patientData/patients.xhtml 404 ()
```

Here's my app config

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");

    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

There's already a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781737/spring-mvc-primefaces-ajax-fails-when-mapping-request-404-error-code) but there's no answer

Anybody familiar with this and can help?

Comment: So this works if you don't use PrimeFaces? I can hardly imagine that. And Spring Web combining with JSF2 is just looking for trouble.

Comment: I haven't tried it without primfaces